# Can we get a tool to strip signatures from multiple posts?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, signatures

The signature policy is clearly stated in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures), but apparently not everyone reads it.

> Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

Normally all it takes is a polite comment and a link to the FAQ to get someone to *stop* appending a signature to every post, but that still leaves them (or us) with a bit of cleanup duty.  If it's only a few posts I don't mind, but sometimes people leave several hundred posts before the signature gets reported.

**Proposal:** Can we get a moderator tool to clean up signatures?  The way I'd like it to function would be to strip the *exact text* that I specify from the end of every post from a specific user.  It might also be nice if we could use it to strip greetings as well, but I find that those are a lot more variable than signatures.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,

Yours truly,

Your friend,

Bill

Comment: What about a tool that stopped the user making any more posts until they have removed the signatures themselfs from all of their posts?

Comment: @Ian: There's one user who has posted signatures on over 1300 (otherwise perfectly good) answers.  I shudder to think how long it would take to clean that up manually.

Comment: */me checks* Ah, good, you don't mean me.  Personally I want whoever cleans up my posts to feel the pain of removing each and every **-Adam** from my early posts.

Comment: @Adam: There is poster with the first name of Tom he is probably talking about. He always signs with Regards, Tom or Best Regards, Tom.

Comment: [A user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/146192/pankaj-khurana) with 80+ questions and near-identical 3 line signatures (Please help me on this/Thanks/Pankaj) on every question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The way I'd like it to function would be to strip the exact text that I specify from the end of every post from a specific user.

There is such a tool, it has existed for a while, but it is ... dangerous ... and as such is limited to developers.

> It might also be nice if we could use it to strip greetings as well, but I find that those are a lot more variable than signatures.

Of course, [I removed most greetings network wide, and they are auto-removed from posts when entered now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989).

Comment: Perfect! A new privilege for 100k+ users ;)   (actually just looked, there's a lot more of them than I expected)

Comment: hehe, I like that, a tool for 100k+ users. @Jeff, what do you think, someone with 100k+ can be trusted, yes?